# CSS help while working In ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, css, master-pages

I have a master page with content placeholders.CSS are applied on this place holders via referencing style sheet in master page.When i use this master page and embed my table in the content placeholder,the CSS which i have applied in the new page which is using master page
is not reflecting as required.

Is there a way to rectify this problem as i can'

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your contentplaceholder into a div and check if that div has given some styles in css file or not. by this way you can check/test if css is being applied on your CPH or not. i.e you should put background-color to black or some different colors to verify...